# Unable to Extract exact key value pairs from log files

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have multiple gzipped log files which have text in between lines of the format:

```
someRandomText... ,"interestingKey":"interestingValue",moreRandomText
```

For this I tried `zgrep -o -i '"interestingKey":[^ ]*' logs*`
Even though it finds the relevant line, it outputs the text before and after the grepped pattern on the line.

Is there a way to limit the results just to the key value pair. And is there a way to also filter the interestingValue to those which have only numbers and no alphabets?

Note: the key has to be case insensitive. The key is always the same. Value is always different.

Comment: That "random text" has the look of JSON. Is it?

Comment: The logs contain a lot of text and json as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
zgrep -oiP '"interestingKey":"\K[^"]*'
```

That will 
find the key name in quotes followed by colon and the opening quote of the value.
Then the `\K` directive "forgets" about the text matched so far.
Then we match some non-quote chars, which `-o` will emit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` lookahead, [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
$ echo 'someRandomText... ,"interestingKey":"interestingValue",moreRandomText' | grep -oP '(?<=interestingKey":).*(?=,)'
"interestingValue"
```

For a file,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=interestingKey":).*(?=,)' inputFile
```

You can use `zgrep` instead of `grep` for gzipped files. Same options should work.

Comment: This is almost what I'm interested in. But it gives out stuff after the value as well. You can assume that the value always ends with a quote. Right now it prints till end of line

Comment: It prints everything between `interestingKey":` and the next comma(`,`). It shouldn't print to the end of the line. Note, `lookahead` input pattern has to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

another one,

```
$ ... | grep -oP '(?<=interestingKey":)[^,]+'
```

you can even strip the quotes if you make it part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `awk`, but this it not the best solution.

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/interestingKey/)print $(i+1)}' file
moreRandomText
```

Since it loops trough all element it some slow.